Django errorlist in form Select Valid Choice
The situation is as follows: I am building a form where I fetch data for some fields from an API. I have tried debugging in every possible way, but I cannot understand why the data is not being persisted in the database. Whenever I click submit, I get the following error:
<ul class="errorlist"><li>municipio<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. Afuá is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>

If anyone can help me understand why this error is occurring, I would appreciate it. To provide context, I am sharing the three main files.
My models.py:
# apps/parametrizacao/models.py

from django.db import models



class RegraFiscal(models.Model):
    REGIME_TRIBUTARIO_CHOICES = [
        ('Simples Nacional', 'Simples Nacional'),
        ('Lucro Presumido', 'Lucro Presumido'),
        ('Lucro Real', 'Lucro Real'),
        ('Misto', 'Misto')
    ]
    
    PORTE_CHOICES = [
        ('ME', 'Microempresa (ME)'),
        ('EPP', 'Empresa de Pequeno Porte (EPP)'),
        ('Demais', 'Demais')
    ]
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Padrão')
    regime_tributario = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=REGIME_TRIBUTARIO_CHOICES)
    porte = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PORTE_CHOICES, default='ME')
    aliquota_csll = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    aliquota_irpj = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    aliquota_pis = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    aliquota_cofins = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    aliquota_icms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    aliquota_ipi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    aliquota_iss = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    aliquota_inss = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nome} - {self.porte}"
    
class Empresa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    inscricao_estadual = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    inscricao_municipal = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    cnae_preponderante = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    natureza_juridica = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    complemento = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uf = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    regra_fiscal = models.ForeignKey(RegraFiscal, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cnpj = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, self.cnpj))  # Remove tudo que não for número antes de salvar
        super(Empresa, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def format_cnpj(self):
        cnpj = self.cnpj
        return f'{cnpj[:2]}.{cnpj[2:5]}.{cnpj[5:8]}/{cnpj[8:12]}-{cnpj[12:]}'
    

my Views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Empresa, RegraFiscal
from .forms import EmpresaForm, RegraFiscalForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.db import transaction

@login_required
def config_empresa(request):
    empresa_id = request.GET.get('id')
    empresa = None
    if empresa_id:
        empresa = get_object_or_404(Empresa, id=empresa_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmpresaForm(request.POST, instance=empresa)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    form.save()
                return redirect('empresa_list')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Erro ao salvar a empresa: {e}")
        else:
            print(f"Erros no formulário: {form.errors}")
    else:
        form = EmpresaForm(instance=empresa)

    return render(request, 'parametrizacao/empresa/config_empresa.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def config_regra_fiscal(request):
    regra_fiscal_id = request.GET.get('id')
    regra_fiscal = None
    if regra_fiscal_id:
        regra_fiscal = get_object_or_404(RegraFiscal, id=regra_fiscal_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegraFiscalForm(request.POST, instance=regra_fiscal)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('regra_fiscal_list')
    else:
        form = RegraFiscalForm(instance=regra_fiscal)

    return render(request, 'parametrizacao/regra_fiscal/config_regra_fiscal.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def empresa_relatorio(request):
    empresas = Empresa.objects.select_related('regra_fiscal').all()
    return render(request, 'parametrizacao/empresa/empresa_relatorio.html', {'empresas': empresas})

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class EmpresaListView(ListView):
    model = Empresa
    template_name = 'parametrizacao/empresa/empresa_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'empresas'

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class EmpresaDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Empresa
    template_name = 'parametrizacao/empresa/empresa_confirm_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('empresa_list')

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class RegraFiscalListView(ListView):
    model = RegraFiscal
    template_name = 'parametrizacao/regra_fiscal/regra_fiscal_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'regras_fiscais'

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class RegraFiscalDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = RegraFiscal
    template_name = 'parametrizacao/regra_fiscal/regra_fiscal_confirm_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('regra_fiscal_list')

My Forms.py:
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import Empresa, RegraFiscal
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit
import requests

class RegraFiscalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegraFiscal
        fields = [
            'nome', 'regime_tributario', 'porte', 'aliquota_csll', 'aliquota_irpj', 'aliquota_pis', 'aliquota_cofins', 
            'aliquota_icms', 'aliquota_ipi', 'aliquota_iss', 'aliquota_inss'
        ]

class EmpresaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cnae_preponderante = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        label='CNAE Preponderante',
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
    uf = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        label='UF',
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'ufSelect'})
    )
    municipio = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        label='Município',
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'municipioSelect'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Empresa
        fields = [
            'nome', 'cnpj', 'inscricao_estadual', 'inscricao_municipal', 'cnae_preponderante', 'natureza_juridica', 
            'endereco', 'numero', 'complemento', 'cep', 'bairro', 'municipio', 'uf', 'email', 'telefone', 'regra_fiscal'
        ]
    def get_cnae_choices(self):
        response = requests.get('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/cnae/classes')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            choices = [(item['id'], f"{item['id']} - {item['descricao']}") for item in data]
            return choices
        return []

    def get_uf_choices(self):
        response = requests.get('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            choices = [(item['sigla'], item['nome']) for item in data]
            return sorted(choices, key=lambda x: x[1])
        return []

    def get_municipio_choices(self, uf=None):
        if not uf:
            return []
        response = requests.get(f'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/{uf}/municipios')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            choices = [(item['nome'], item['nome']) for item in data]
            return choices
        return []


    def clean_cnpj(self):
        cnpj = self.cleaned_data['cnpj']
        cnpj = cnpj.replace('.', '').replace('/', '').replace('-', '')
        if len(cnpj) != 14 or not cnpj.isdigit():
            raise forms.ValidationError("CNPJ inválido")
        return cnpj
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmpresaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Salvar'))
        self.fields['cnae_preponderante'].choices = self.get_cnae_choices()
        self.fields['uf'].choices = self.get_uf_choices()
        print(self.get_uf_choices)
        print(self.get_municipio_choices)

        # Atualiza os municípios com base na UF selecionada
        if 'data' in kwargs:
            uf = kwargs['data'].get('uf')
            self.fields['municipio'].choices = self.get_municipio_choices(uf)
        elif self.instance and self.instance.uf:
            self.fields['municipio'].choices = self.get_municipio_choices(self.instance.uf)
        else:
            self.fields['municipio'].choices = []

my Template:
{% extends "dashboard/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Adicionar Empresa{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card card-primary">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Adicionar Empresa</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" id="empresaForm">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.nome|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.cnpj|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.inscricao_estadual|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.inscricao_municipal|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.cnae_preponderante|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.natureza_juridica|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.endereco|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.numero|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.complemento|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.cep|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="ufSelect">UF</label>
                  <select id="ufSelect" name="uf" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Selecione a UF</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="municipioSelect">Município</label>
                  <select id="municipioSelect" name="municipio" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Selecione o Município</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.bairro|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.telefone|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.regra_fiscal|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00');

  function preencherUF() {
    $.getJSON('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados', function(data) {
      var ufSelect = $('#ufSelect');
      ufSelect.empty();
      ufSelect.append('<option value="">Selecione a UF</option>');
      $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        ufSelect.append('<option value="'+ value.sigla +'">'+ value.nome +'</option>');
      });

      console.log("UFs carregadas:", data);
    });
  }

  function atualizarMunicipios(uf) {
    if (uf) {
      $.getJSON('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/'+ uf +'/municipios', function(data) {
        var municipioSelect = $('#municipioSelect');
        municipioSelect.empty();
        municipioSelect.append('<option value="">Selecione o Município</option>');
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
          municipioSelect.append('<option value="'+ value.nome +'">'+ value.nome +'</option>');
        });

        console.log("Municípios carregados para UF", uf, ":", data);

      }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
      });
    } else {
      $('#municipioSelect').empty();
      $('#municipioSelect').append('<option value="">Selecione o Município</option>');
      console.log("UF não selecionada. MunicípioSelect esvaziado.");
    }
  }

  preencherUF();

  $('#ufSelect').change(function() {
    var uf = $(this).val();
    atualizarMunicipios(uf);
    console.log("UF alterada para:", uf);
  });


  $('#empresaForm').submit(function(event) {
    var selectedMunicipio = $('#municipioSelect').val();
    console.log("Município selecionado ao enviar:", selectedMunicipio);

    if (!selectedMunicipio || !$('#municipioSelect option[value="'+selectedMunicipio+'"]').length) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('Por favor, selecione um município válido.');
    } else {
      $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'municipio',
        value: selectedMunicipio
      }).appendTo('#empresaForm');
    }
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}


I am trying to select the UF (State) and the municipioSelect (chosen city) in the form in such a way that this selection is made via a public API that provides all the cities in Brazil.
However, when I click submit, the form returns the correct city, as shown in my debug:
console.log("Selected municipality on submit:", selectedMunicipio);


The correct city is logged.
However, when it goes to validate in the database, the data is not submitted, meaning the data is not persisted. There is an issue with the update because when I click to edit a form where the state is already loaded in the database, it allows me to change the city of that state and persists the change. But when I change the state and it updates the list of municipalities, it causes a problem.
